# SwiftUI Get User's Location When Button is Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

New to Swift/SwiftUI, but currently developing an app with SwiftUI and have reached a stopping point because I cannot figure out for the life of me how to simply get the user's current location when they tap a button. SURELY this cannot be this hard?! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All I'm after really is to get the user ultimately be able to drop a pin on a map (using `MapKit`) at their current location when they tap a button.

Comment: Assuming you've got the entitlement and the user has allowed your app to use location services, call `CLLocationManager`'s [`requestLocation()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) method.

Comment: The work has to be done in your model - have a function that you can call when the button is tapped; it can call `requestLocation`. Have the delegate method for your location manager update a published location property in your model. Your view can use this updated property to add the annotation to the map

Comment: I had found this during my research, but I don't know how to implement the ViewController with SwiftUI. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-request-a-users-location-only-once-using-requestlocation I've been going through tutorials for SwiftUI, but this was the first time I've seen anything with a ViewController.

Comment: I don't know how in the world you implement the above code from that link within the context of SwiftUI let alone within a button's action.

Comment: Using SwiftUI is going to be an additional challenge as you will need to use a hosting view to get the MKMapView into your SwiftUI views. Once you have done that it should be pretty straightforward. You don't need to worry bout view controllers. You just need to update your model and make sure that you map view uses the model to add an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CLLocationManager, you can call the `requestLocation`() method... You can use an @IBAction for when the button is pressed, and just call the `requestLocation()` method inside this IBAction! I hope this helped!

Comment: PS: Make sure the user has allowed your app to use location services, or else it won't work!